# Cannot map array using getDocs to read data for a Flatlist

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, flatlist

I have an Expo project with this code to retrieve a collection from Firestore:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {...};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);


const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getEvents = async (dbx) => {
      const eventsCol = collection(dbx, 'testing');
      const eventSnapshot = await getDocs(eventsCol);
      const eventList = eventSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
        ({
          ...doc.data(),
          key: doc.id
        })
      );
      console.log("Event list inside: ",eventList);
      return eventList;
    }
    setEvents(getEvents(db));
    console.log("Events: ",events);
}, []);
```

The console prints this inside the function, which is the array I need to display in a Flatlist.

```
Event list inside:  Array [
  Object {
    "features": Object {
      "best": "movement",
      "better": "arm",
      "good": "read",
    },
    "height": "1.91",
    "key": "63eM32mC897nvK2ZvdWz",
    "name": "Mahomes",
  },
  Object {
    "features": Object {
      "best": "audibles",
      "better": "arm",
      "good": "pocket",
    },
    "height": "1.98",
    "key": "FavrYCjD1ls56wKOMQPg",
    "name": "Manning",
  },
  Object {
    "features": Object {
      "best": "strength",
      "better": "arm",
      "good": "reads",
    },
    "height": "1.98",
    "key": "eaM8ipLVrn9OEg35SLgk",
    "name": "Herbert",
  },
]
```

But after calling setEvents I get this structure which of course won't work with FL

```
    Events:  Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 1,
  "_W": Array [
    Object {
      "features": Object {
        "best": "movement",
        "better": "arm",
        "good": "read",
      },
      "height": "1.91",
      "key": "63eM32mC897nvK2ZvdWz",
      "name": "Mahomes",
    },
    Object {
      "features": Object {
        "best": "audibles",
        "better": "arm",
        "good": "pocket",
      },
      "height": "1.98",
      "key": "FavrYCjD1ls56wKOMQPg",
      "name": "Manning",
    },
    Object {
      "features": Object {
        "best": "strength",
        "better": "arm",
        "good": "reads",
      },
      "height": "1.98",
      "key": "eaM8ipLVrn9OEg35SLgk",
      "name": "Herbert",
    },
  ],
  "_X": null,
}
```

I can't find any documentation or examples and I'm kind of new to React-Native, any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
setEvents(getEvents(db));
```

call only

```
getEvents(db)
```

and within your getEvents function call

```
setEvents(eventList)
```

this way you're setting the events state variable to be the mapped data instead of the function call, which appears to be returning the entire Promise instead of just the response.